# Помогите с редиректом в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно переадресовать через .htaccess со страницы
**http://mysite.ru/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap**
на
**http://mysite.ru/sitemap.xml**

данные варианты ни к чему не приводят:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)/google_sitemap /sitemap.xml
# ------
Redirect 301 index\.php\?route=feed/google_sitemap /sitemap.xml
# ------
Redirect 301 /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap /sitemap.xml
# ------
Redirect mysite.ru/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap mysite.ru/sitemap.xml
# ------
RewriteRule /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap /sitemap.xml
# ------
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте проанализировать `QUERY_STRING` отдельно:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=feed/google_sitemap$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /sitemap.xml [R=301,L]

# Если нужно отбросить route=feed/google_sitemap, то:

# Для Apache 2.4.0 и выше нужно использовать флаг [QSD]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /sitemap.xml [R=301,L,QSD]

# Для предыдущих версий нужно добавить ? в конец целевого URL
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /sitemap.xml? [R=301,L]
```

Проверил с помощью [htaccess tester'а](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be) — в таком виде все отлично работает.

Comment: чёт ерунда получается: http://mysite.ru/sitemap.xml?route=feed/google_sitemap

Comment: за ссылку спасибо! Думаю пригодиться!

Comment: понял, в конец /sitemap.xml  нужно добавить "?" Если вам нужно отбрасывать оригинальную QUERY_STRING, нужно к правилу добавить "?".

Comment: Все верно. Дополнил свой ответ. Посмотрите вариант для Apache 2.4.0 и выше, там все решается добавлением флага `[QSD]`